# What does the rsync filter -f 'hide,! */' do?

Tags: bash, terminal, rsync

I want to sync only specific files with rsync. I found:

```
rsync --include='SpecificFiles*' -f 'hide,! */' ~/src ~/dst
```

The "include" is obvious, but what does the "-f ..." part do?
Thank you!

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-f

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you: http://blog.mudflatsoftware.com/blog/2012/10/31/tricks-with-rsync-filter-rules/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rsync --include='SpecificFiles*' -f 'hide,! */' ~/src ~/dst
```

First, the --`include` tells rsync to copy everything matching `SpecificFiles*`.

Second, the rule `-f 'hide,! */'` hides all non-directories.  This means that no regular file is copied unless it was matched by the previous include rule.

In more detail, `hide,` starts a hide rule.  Since `*/` matches all directories, its negation `! */` matches all non-directories.  Thus, `-f 'hide,! */'` hides all non-directories.

As an aside, *hide* is similar to *exclude* unless a delete option is also specified. In that case, if a file that was *hidden* is already at the destination, it *will* be deleted just as if it did not exist at the source.  By contrast, if a file that was *excluded* is already at the destination, the destination file *will not* be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

```
-f, --filter=RULE    add a file-filtering RULE
-F                   same as --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'
```

`-f 'hide,! */'` hides all non-directories.

Why don't you read the [following](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync%20-f)?

Also, have you even tried `rsync --help`?

Comment: If you read my question carefully (especially the title), you would see that I know that "-f" calls a filter. The question is: what does the filter do.